# WebRTC AGC (Automatic Gain Control)

Tags: c++, signal-processing, webrtc

I am testing the WebRTC AGC but I must be doing something wrong because the signal just passes through unmodified.

Here's how I create and initialize the AGC:

```
agcConfig.compressionGaindB = 9;
agcConfig.limiterEnable = 1;
agcConfig.targetLevelDbfs = 9;   /* 9dB below full scale */

WebRtcAgc_Create(&agc);
WebRtcAgc_Init(agc, minLevel, maxLevel, kAgcModeFixedDigital, 8000);
WebRtcAgc_set_config(agc, agcConfig);
```

And then for each 10ms sample block I do the following:

```
WebRtcAgc_Process(agc, micData, NULL, 80, micData, NULL, micLevelIn, &micLevelOut, 0, &saturationWarning);
```

Where `micLevelIn` is set to 0.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I expected that a full scale sine tone would be attenuated to the target DBFS level; and a low level sine tone (i.e. -30dBFS) would be amplified to match the target DBFS level. But that's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: Are you sure there is absolutely no "spike" noise that is preventing the AGC from amplifying the input signal as you expect it to? Also take a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12712228/319204); is `WebRtcAgc_Process()` expected to set `micLevelOut` appropriately and leave it at that?...

Comment: A nice little description of [**`WebRtcAgc_Process()`**](http://osxr.org/android/source/external/webrtc/src/modules/audio_processing/agc/interface/gain_control.h#0133) to help sort out your expectations.

Comment: Does `WebRtcAgc_Process()` consider the sine wave input as non-speech segment and hence skips it? Can you try passing an actual speech clip and test?

Comment: Also checking out the source-code of webrtc, the param [`vadLogRatio`](http://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/agc/analog_agc.c?spec=svn5571&r=5571#944) is derived from `micLevelIn` passed to `WebRtcAgc_Process`. If this is set to **`0`** then it always happens to be less than the calculated `stt->vadThreshold`. Hence the input sample is NOT detected as speech and hence is passed out untouched. Just a thought...

Comment: Please dont flag c++ code as C, it is confusing.

Comment: I have used the similar code . however in my case the output results in -1 ( error ) so far . Anyways can u share if you have received any saturationWarning so far ? Also additionally I understand that the speech output is a combined  effect of resulting dbfs , compression gain adn few more parameters .  I note that this might not be very helpful but I need to ensure that this works so that I can employ the same . Please share if you have cracked the problem already

Answer (score 3):

Here is the sequence of operations to be used for Webrtc_AGC:

1. Create AGC: `WebRtcAgc_Create`
2. Initialize AGC:  `WebRtcAgc_Init`
3. Set Config: `WebRtcAgc_set_config`
4. Initialize `capture_level = 0`
5. For `kAgcModeAdaptiveDigital`, invoke VirtualMic: `WebRtcAgc_VirtualMic`
6. Process Buffer with `capture_level`: `WebRtcAgc_Process`
7. Get the out capture level returned from `WebRtcAgc_Process` and set it to `capture_level`
8. Repeat 5 to 7 for the `audio buffers`
9. Destroy the AGC: `WebRtcAgc_Free`

Check webrtc/modules/audio_processing/gain_control_impl.cc for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    agcConfig.compressionGaindB = 9;
    agcConfig.limiterEnable = 1;
    agcConfig.targetLevelDbfs = 9;   /* 9dB below full scale */

    WebRtcAgc_Create(&agc);
    WebRtcAgc_Init(&agc, minLevel, maxLevel, kAgcModeFixedDigital, 8000);
    WebRtcAgc_set_config(&agc, &agcConfig);
```